# Deleting a file from Windows 7 Recycle Bin that causes deletion to hang

Tags: windows-7, recycle-bin

This is a WMV file that resulted from a failed operation in some video transcoding software a couple years ago.  The resulting file did not ever play correctly in video-playing software.  I moved the file to the Recycle Bin and once there using the GUI I was not able either to delete the file for good or to restore it (the popup dialog "Calculating.." would hang).  I'm getting similar results on the command line.

From a `cmd.exe` session run as administrator (some numbers have been anonymized):

```
C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-21-4124927541-9264348802-7345726938-1000>dir
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is ZZZZ-ZZZZ

 Directory of C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-21-4124927541-9264348802-7345726938-1000

10/13/2012  02:35 PM       357,098,311 $RSW0FIC.wmv
               1 File(s)    357,098,311 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  185,479,229,440 bytes free

C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-21-4124927541-9264348802-7345726938-1000>del $RSW0FIC.wmv
C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-21-4124927541-9264348802-7345726938-1000\$RSW0FIC.wmv
The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an applica
tion request.
```

I'm not sure why the filename is shown here as `$RSW0FIC.wmv`, it was named `squire.wmv` before I started hacking away at it.  The message `The I/O operation has been aborted..` is the result of my hitting `Ctrl+C` as the `del` operation was hanging.

What else can I try to delete this file?  I do have access to some Unix-y type commands as I have UnxUtils or Git Bash or something installed on the machine.  I've tried `del`, `mv`, and `rm` and they all hang.

This is on Windows 7 Pro SP1 and it's a hard disk formatted NTFS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

http://www.thewindowsclub.com/recycle-bin-is-corrupted-windows

Make sure you open Command Prompt as Administrator before you do, and make sure you restart your PC afterwards.

**EDIT:** For stubborn issues do this in *Safe Mode* (F8 at boot). Thanks to **Tyler** for pointing that out.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This is also hanging unfortunately. Any way around it?  `C:\>rd /s /q C:\$Recycle.Bin`  
`C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-~1\$RSW0FIC.wmv - The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.` (after `Ctrl+C`)

Comment: Try this in Safe Mode with Command Prompt. Reboot your computer and press F8 before windows loads to get to Safe Mode with Command Prompt. If that doesn't work, run a disk check to fix corrupted files and then try again.

Comment: Running @misha256's command in Safe Mode with Command Prompt as you suggest worked beautifully, thank you both!